# Should one write Big Oh complexity in the documentation of algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, complexity

When writing or using an algorithm, should the Big Oh complexity be mentioned?

Comment: Only if you're showing your "O" face

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can back it up with real analysis, then yes, absolutely.

@Casebash test != analysis.  If it should always be documented then just start throwing

 `// this algorithm is O(n!)` 
on every function.  
I've worked with people who would say things like 'This function is O(1) because there are no loops', and then I would point to the call `$(someHugeList).each(function(//...`

Comment: Then perhaps the question should be "Should you do the analysis?"

Comment: @finnw Sorry, your point is...what exactly?

Comment: @downvoter Awesome down vote for a perfectly reasonable answer with no comment to explain.

Comment: I don't like this answer either. It should be always documented, even if you haven't tested it

Comment: @Casebash: If you haven't analyzed your algorithm, then how can you know what its Big-O even *is*? Analysis (even very simply analysis) is a prerequisite. If you can't back up your statement of complexity, then it is wrong.

Comment: @Casebash see update

Comment: For always documentation one should probably add "unless analysis proofs it's better."

Comment: @TomWij - that's my point ... **analysis** :)

Comment: @BioBuckyBall, functions exist worse than O(n!).  See Ackermann.